# How to conditionally fetch within useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was able  to fetch a new quote every time I re-render, but now I want to add a functionality where I have the option to replay the same quote and not fetch a new one if I press the replay quote button, however I still want to call the useEffect. The solution to this sounds super straight forward, however, I do not know how to approach it with useEffect in play.

Also, when using react is it better to use ref hooks, instead of document.getElementByID ?

[Code SandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-hypatia-sd3u3q?file=/src/App.js:0-1050)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

async function newQuote() {
  const response = await fetch("https://api.quotable.io/random");
  const data = await response.json();

  return data.content;
}

async function genQuote() {
  document.getElementById("quoteDisplay").innerText = await newQuote();
}

export default function App() {
  const [quote, fecthNewQuote] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    genQuote();

    document.getElementById(
      "newQuoteCounter"
    ).innerText = `New Quote Counter: ${quote}`;

    document.getElementById("quoteReplayedCounter").innertext = ``;
  }, [quote]);

  console.log();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="quoteDisplay"></div>
      <div id="newQuoteCounter">New Quote Counter: 0</div>
      <div id="quoteReplayedCounter"> Quote Replayed Counter: 0 </div>
      <button id="newQuoteButton" onClick={() => fecthNewQuote((c) => c + 1)}>
        Fetch New Quote
      </button>
      <button id="keepSameQuote">Keep Same Quote</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor like this with async function inside `useEffect` and you do not need to use these kind of  `document.getElementById("quoteDisplay").innerText` js solutions. You can do it with react states.

Here is the working example https://codesandbox.io/embed/distracted-shamir-sfinbd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [quote, fecthNewQuote] = useState(0);
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function newQuote() {
      const response = await fetch("https://api.quotable.io/random");
      const data = await response.json();
      setDisplay(data.content);
    }
    newQuote();
  }, [quote]);

  console.log();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="quoteDisplay">{display}</div>
      <div id="newQuoteCounter">New Quote Counter: {quote}</div>
      <div id="quoteReplayedCounter"> Quote Replayed Counter: 0 </div>
      <button id="newQuoteButton" onClick={() => fecthNewQuote(quote + 1)}>
        Fetch New Quote
      </button>
      <button id="keepSameQuote">Keep Same Quote</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please choose it as accepted answer if it solved your issue, you are welcome :) @t0ken97c